# Calculation with WEEK in oracle

Tags: sql, date, plsql, week-number

I am comparing two dates in oracle where I stuck at one point in which I have to compare my week with the current week.

Suppose today is `05-Jan-2015` and it's a first week and input date is `29_Dec-2014` and I'm executing below statement to compare:

```
ld_week BETWEEN FOCUS_WEEK-4 AND FOCUS_WEEK-1
```

where:

- ld_week is the week from input date (last week of current year)
- focus_week is week from current date (first week of next year)

hence (52 BETWEEN (1-4) AND (1-1)) always fails.

I am using below function to calculate the week.

```
FOCUS_WEEK := to_number(to_char(to_date(focus_day),'WW'));
```

Please let me know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague. I believe you want to try

```
        trunk(date '2014-12-29', 'd')
between
        trunk(sysdate - 4*7    , 'd') and
        trunk(sysdate - 1*7    , 'd')
```

With `trunc(date, 'd')` you obtain the start date of a week.